# How to change state of UI elements of a cell in Custom Table View on its selection?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My table view looks like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return appsName!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.appTimeLabel.isHidden = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.appNameLabel.text = appsName![indexPath.row]
    cell.appTimeLabel.text = appTimeLimit![indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

My table view cell class :

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var appNameLabel: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var setLimitButton: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var appIcon: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var appTimeLabel: UILabel!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
   }

}
```

My row selection function :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        array[indexPath.row] = !array[indexPath.row]       
}
```

Array for boolean values:

```
var array = [Bool](repeating:false, count: 200)
```

This is my code and I want to show unlimited label and set Limit button in my cell on its selection:

[image]

Initially setlimit button and unlimited label is set to hidden.

Actual working cell screenshot(android):

[image]
[image]

How to do this?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: You can use `reloadData()` or `reloadRows(at:with:)` with your appropriate values or specific condition that use for hide/show.

Comment: **Never** use multiple arrays as data source. That's very bad practice. Use a custom struct and include `name` and `limit` and the `isSelected` information. In `didSelectRowAt` modify the properties and reload the row.

Comment: While reloading the row on selection, my checkbox just flashes the blue dot and turns to white/not selected. It is updating but not showing blue dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a dictionary for your cells data like this;

```
  var myDic = [["appName": "app1",
             "appTime": "unlimited",
             "isSelected": true,
    ], ["appName": "app2",
             "appTime": "unlimited",
             "isSelected": true,
    ]
]
```

After you can use its count like this;

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return myDic.count
}
```

If you change your checkbox status according to "isSelected" value from dictionary your problem will solve;

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



    let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if (myDic[indexPath.row]["isSelected"] as? Bool) == true {
        myDic[indexPath.row]["isSelected"] = false
    } else {
        myDic[indexPath.row]["isSelected"] = true
    }
    cell.appTimeLabel.isHidden = !(myDic[indexPath.row]["isSelected"] != nil)
    cell.setLimitButton.isHidden = !(myDic[indexPath.row]["isSelected"] != nil)
    cell.selectionBox.isSelected = (myDic[indexPath.row]["isSelected"] != nil)

    myTableView.reloadData()

}
```